# How to show the number of time series of all measurement points within certain time of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask, is there a way to query the number of time series data of all measurement points within a certain time period in Apache IoTDB? If I also need to do visual monitoring in real-time for this kind of data, any suggestions on how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable metrics on Apache IoTDB to count the data you want, and can record these data through prometheus. Then use Grafana to pull the metric monitoring information of prometheus, which can be seen through visual monitoring.